# What's an example of a rough path that's not Ito/Stratonovich-Brownian rough path?

Tags: rough-paths

The only rough path that I've ever seen discussed are the ones associated with Brownian motion. I could use a "rough path" for any nice function, defeating the point. In particular are there interesting rough paths that are $\alpha$-Holder continuous for $\frac13 \lt \alpha \lt \frac12$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[An explicit rough path construction for continuous paths with arbitrary Hölder exponent](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00370570/document), by Jeremie Unterberger (2009) [[published](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00220-010-1064-1) with a different title]:

> We construct an explicit geometric rough path over arbitrary
>   $d$-dimensional paths with finite $1/\alpha$-variation for any
>   $\alpha\in (0, 1)$. The method generalizes to arbitrary $\alpha$-Hölder paths the previous constructions that were limited to fractional Brownian motion. Our generalization may
>   be coined as *Fourier normal ordering* since it consists in a
>   regularization obtained after permuting the order of integration in
>   iterated integrals so that innermost integrals have highest Fourier
>   frequencies. The method is not limited to Brownian motion, because it does not rely on tools belonging exclusively to the Gaussian realm, namely, the equivalence of $L^p$-norms due to the hypercontractivity property of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

For a broader overview of this topic with many examples, starting from T. Lyon's seminal contributions, see Unterberger's [Rough Path Theory](http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~unterber/book-rough-paths.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

1) Fractional Brownian motion (with the lift given by limit of piecewise linear approximations or any reasonable convolution approximation à la Wong-Zakai).

2) Actually as pointed out before any continuous Hölder path can be lifted to a geometric RP (a result originally due to Lions-Victoir).

3) Physical brownian motion in a magnetic field. http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.2531

4) Solutions to SPDEs (see Hairer's "Solving the KPZ equation")

5) Smooth rough paths: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmi/1204128313

Answer (score 1):

A Levy rough path for a Levy process not a Brownian motion.

Take a look at Friz and Shekhar [General rough integration, Levy rough paths and a Levy-Kintchine type formula](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5888v2.pdf).

Regarding the Holder condition, don't Brownian motions themselves qualify?

Comment: Brownian motion indeed does qualify for Holder condition does qualify, but I am looking for other examples. Thanks for the resource.

Comment: And other issue: "On the rough-paths approach to non-commutative stochastic calculus". Look her https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6238